# Process and convert array of bytes to string

Tags: kaitai-struct

I'm trying to generate the structure of a FamousWriter file (fwd).
I'm halfway through the file.
I'm using the WEB IDE, and I'd like to see the translation to string of the byte arrays I've found.

This should be doable with **process** and **encoding** but I'm struck by a unkown key found error.

As an example, the string:

```
10 00 3F 79 7D 77 3F 67 79 7E 74 7F 67 24 3E 7A 60 77
```

is shown in it's ASCII form:

```
?y}w?gy~tg$>z`w
```

But I know the first byte (in this case '*10*') it's the encryption key.

So, after processing it:

```
00 10 2F 69 6D 67 2F 77 69 6E 64 6F 77 34 2E 6A 70 67
```

And it would be shown as:

```
/img/window4.jpg
```

My code at the moment is:

```
  - id: firstfile
    type: file_name
    repeat: expr
    repeat-expr: 1
```

```
  file_name:
    seq:
    - id: sizedecoder
      type: u2
    - id: data
      size: sizedecoder
      process: xor(sizedecoder)
      #type: str
      #encoding: SJIS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Affiliate disclaimer: I'm a [Kaitai Struct](https://kaitai.io/) maintainer (see my [GitHub profile](https://github.com/generalmimon)).

As of Kaitai Struct 0.10, using `type: str` and `process` on the same attribute hasn't been implemented yet. See https://github.com/kaitai-io/kaitai_struct/issues/503 and https://github.com/kaitai-io/kaitai_struct/issues/706#issuecomment-590125139:

> 2. using `process` is not implemented on `str`ing type at all. I don't think it's intentional, it's just another bug.
>
> But it's easy to work around both issues, you can also wrap it into a new user type.

So in your case, you should add a wrapper type for the string - let's call it `str_wrapper`:

```yaml
  file_name:
    seq:
      - id: sizedecoder
        type: u2
      - id: data
        size: sizedecoder
        process: xor(sizedecoder)
        type: str_wrapper

  str_wrapper:
    seq:
      - id: value
        size-eos: true
        type: str
        encoding: SJIS
```